# Split data from row in db and then show selected in dropdown

Tags: php

I have a field in my database called 'experience' which typically looks like this

`Telesales,Face to face,`

I also then have a drop down box on the 'edit profile' section which looks like this

I call the users information with '$user->experience' (this will display from the field experience)

```
<option value="Telesales">Telesales</option>
  <option value="Party Planning">Party Planning</option>
  <option value="Door to Door">Door to Door</option>
  <option value="Face to Face">Face to Face</option>
  <option value="Online Demos">Online Demos</option>
  <option value="Affiliate Link">Affiliate Link</option>
  <option value="Appointment Setting">Appointment Setting</option>
```

I am wondering the best way to get the data, remove the commas and then echo "selected" on the options that the user pre selected when creating their account.

Comment: You mean [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string on comma (`,`) and foreach element print the option value?

Comment: FYI, if your option value and option text are the same, you can omit the value.  `<option>Telesales</option>` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
$options = explode(",", "A,B,C,D,E,F,G");
$userSelection = explode(",", "A,C,F");

echo '<form>';
foreach ($options as $val) {
   echo '<input type="checkbox"';
   if (in_array($val,$userSelection)) echo 'checked';
   echo " />$val<br />";
}
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what I meant, Basically i want to still have all the options, but some users may select 1, or 2 options and not the remaining, so i want to echo 'selected' on the drop down options that the user has chosen which is stored in the db